# convergence of $u_n$ when $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{u_n}{ v_n} =0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

we have$ :\sum_{}^{}v_n$ convergent. $u_n>0$,$v_n>0$

so lets show that :

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=0  $ $ \Rightarrow$$\sum_{}^{}u_n$ convergent

we know that:

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=0  $$\Rightarrow$  $\forall \epsilon>0 , \exists N \in \mathbb{N}  ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$\Rightarrow$$|\frac{u_n}{v_n} |<\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow$  $u_n <\epsilon v_n$ for all$ n \in \mathbb{N}$ when n go to infini ,because in this cas n will always be greater than N

so now we can say $u_n$convergent,  because  we have $\sum_{}{} v_n $ is convergent and $\epsilon >0$

Is this proof enough?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient. You need to show the Cauchy Criterion: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m\ge n}\sum_{j=n}^mu_n=0.$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n/v_n=0$  implies the weaker condition $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m\ge n}u_n/v_n<\infty.$ This latter condition implies that $\sum_n u_n$ converges, as follows:

There exists $K>0$ such that $\forall n\, (u_n/v_n\le K)$. So for any $m,n$ with $m\ge n$ we have $\sum_{j=n}^mu_n\le K\sum_{j=n}^mv_n .$

Hence $\sup_{m\ge n}\sum_{j=n}^mu_n \le K\sup_{m\ge n}\sum_{j=n}^mv_n.$ Therefore we have$$0\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m\ge n}\sum_{j=n}^mu_n \le \lim_{n\to\infty}K\sup_{m\ge n}\sum_{j=n}^mv_n=$$ $$=K\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m\ge n}\sum_{j=n}^mv_n=K\cdot 0=0$$ because $\sum_nv_n$ satisfies the Cauchy Criterion.

Note this is not valid if  $v_n$ can be either $+$ or $-.$ E.g. if $v_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt n$ and $u_n=1/n.$ However if (i) every $v_n\ge 0,$ and (ii) $\sum_n v_n$ converges, and (iii) there exists $K >0$ such that $\{n\in\Bbb N: |u_n|> Kv_n\}$ is a finite set, then $\sum_nu_n$ converges without needing the condition $u_n\ge 0$. This is called "By comparison to the absolutely convergent series $\sum_nKv_n.$"

Note also  there is no $\infty$ in $\Bbb R$ so whenever we write "$=\infty$" or "$<\infty$" as I did, it is understood as an abbreviation for a longer precise phrase